# Syntax meaning for flutter

Tags: class, object, flutter, dart

There is a syntax in the code "?."

The usage is ..

```
ClassName objectName;
objectName?.function();
```

Here the function is in the class. Why is the question mark used ?
what type of syntax is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a null aware operator. See this post: https://flutterigniter.com/checking-null-aware-operators-dart/

Specifically under the heading 'Safe Navigation Operator'

Answer (score 0):

This is a "conditional member access" operator (see official [docs](https://dart.dev/language/operators#other-operators)), which guarantees that the `function()` in question is not attempted on a null object.

Also, since dart `2.1.12` there is the neat "cascade notation", like so `..`, which allows you to "to make a sequence of operations on the same object". , You can combine it with the null-check operator `?` to make `?..`; this specifically is referred to as a "null-shorting cascade".

See official [docs](https://dart.dev/language/operators#cascade-notation) on that matter.

Example:

```
var submitButton = querySelector('#submit-button');
?..onClick.listen((_) => {}); //null-shorting necessary only on first call
 ..scrollIntoView();
```